# USB will not work after most recent update

Tags: 10.10, usb

I have had Ubuntu 10.10 for a year with no problems and completely love it... two days ago I did my latest updates through update manager and now my USB ports do not work... I use a mouse because my trackpad is terrible.

The mouse lights up, so it has power, but it will not move. I've tried my printer and phone as well to no avail. Any tips would be greatly appreciated...

After typing `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` in the terminal, it repeatedly says **"unable to enumerate USB device on port 1"** over and over again... `sudo lsusb` shows my mouse.

```
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:09b8 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)