# Lenovo W520 back usb port not working

Tags: usb, lenovo

The usb port in the back of my laptop (on the right side when viewed from using perspective) is not working.

Does anybody know if we can get this port working, and what the port number is.

Here is my `lsusb`, if it can help.

```
% lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c01e Logitech, Inc. MX518 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c318 Logitech, Inc. Illuminated Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0765:5001 X-Rite, Inc. Huey PRO Colorimeter
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f2:b217 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Lenovo Integrated Camera (0.3MP)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 17ef:1003 Lenovo Integrated Smart Card Reader
```

I am running 12.10, upgraded from 12.04 but it did not work either in 12.04.

The two usb ports on the left work just fine.

**EDIT:**

I just updated my bios from 1.32 to 1.39, no change in behaviour.

The port does not even power up my devices.

**EDIT 2:**

Booted up windows, and the port is working.

I went into the device manager and looked at the USB settings.

I found my USB drive on Port 2, Hub 3, i just don't know how that relates to the Bus and Device numbers of linux.

In windows, Smart card reader was on USB hub located at port 1 hub 2, fingerprint and bluetooth were on USB hub located at port 1 hub 1

**EDIT 3:**

Went and looked at [this SO post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104935/usb-will-not-work-after-most-recent-update?rq=1). Tried to look at my kern.log file with `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`. Got some activity when plugging/removing devices in other ports, but nothing happens when connecting a device into that port. It really looks disabled.

Looked at my usb1-4 `sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/control` and they are all set on auto. As expected, usb4 have version 3.00, the others (usb1-usb3) are 2.00.

Comment: @user68186 See new edit for Windows boot. thx. It is not a USB 3.0 port (it's yellow) but the mouse and keyboard are in blue ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating Ubuntu to 13.04, the port just started working. `lsusb` gives the same results as before, but now i can connect to that port.

I know this is not a real answer, as it does not fix the problem from the original question as-is, but upgrading works.